# CKEditor and elFinder in modal dialog

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, modal-dialog, elfinder

I need to integrate elFinder to CKEditor. I followed this:

https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Integration-with-CKEditor

It is working but opening pop-up window for image selection is not very nice so I want to open elFinder in modal dialog.

For "modal integration" i followed this thread:
http://bxuulgygd9.tal.ki/20110728/integration-with-ckeditor-759177/

The last post there partially works. It really opens elfinder in modal. BUT:
When I want to insert image URL to URL field in CKFinder I have to know its exact ID. Is also does not fill image resolution and brings some other problems. The best solution would be to run function called in "ordinary popup" integration, which handles everything:

```
window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(funcNum, file);
```

But in "popup integration", **funcNum** callback is registered, in modal integration **it is not** so I'm unable call it. Do you have any tip to run elfinder (or any other image manager - it would be the same) in modal window? I'm desperate.

Answer (score 5):

I have solved it myself. This code is combination of several tutorials and allows to fully integrate elFinder in modal window. Maybe somebody will consider it useful.

```
    CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(event) {
    var editor = event.editor;
    var dialogDefinition = event.data.definition;
    console.log(event.editor);
    var dialogName = event.data.name;

    var tabCount = dialogDefinition.contents.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {
        var browseButton = dialogDefinition.contents[i].get('browse');

        if (browseButton !== null) {
            browseButton.hidden = false;
            browseButton.onClick = function(dialog, i) {
                editor._.filebrowserSe = this;
                jQuery('<div \>').dialog({modal: true, width: "80%", title: "Insert image", zIndex: 99999,
                    create: function(event, ui) {
                        jQuery(this).elfinder({
                            resizable: false,
                            url: "/path/to/connector.php",
                            getFileCallback: function(url) {
                                CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(editor._.filebrowserFn, url);
                                jQuery('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close[role="button"]').click()
                            }
                        }).elfinder('instance')
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: hi, i get an error in firebug with this code. ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined

Comment: Oh yeah this makes more sense then putting it in the elfinder.html and include ckeditor there.. Its working fine btw, but it seems i have some problems with the zIndex cause it opens like this: http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/2707/elfinder.png and i cant access the finder just if i close the first window. Do you have any idea?

Comment: i found a way: i have to replace the zIndex with dialogClass: "ui-max-index" and make a class in css .ui-max-index { z-index:99999 !important;} with this it will work perfect. And in the CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(editor._.filebrowserFn, url); u must return url['path']

Comment: Thank you, Barta. I'm doing front-end libraries update and your comments helped me a lot!